# Openssl output hanging when getting -enddate

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssl, openssl

I've have been working on a script to get some certificate details and not that I've got the formatting on its way to being ironed out the script now hangs when I attempt to parse `EndDate="openssl s_client -connect $host:$port 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -enddate -noout | grep "Not After" | awk '{print $4, $5, $7}'"`.

This is the full script I'm currently working on for reference, much of it is hacked together since I'm just getting the hang of scripting.

```
# User input for the host or url of the certificate to check 
echo "What host IP or URL certificate would you like to check: "
    read host
# User input for the port number of the certificate to check
echo "What is the port number for the host's IP or URL: "
    read port
# Input Verification post
echo "Host connection information = $host:$port"
# openssl expiration date checks for the week
echo "::Certificate expiration date::"
EndDate=`openssl s_client -connect $host:$port 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -   enddate -noout | grep "Not After" | awk '{print $4, $5, $7}'`
DatePlus7=`date -ud "+7 day" | awk '{print $2, $3, $6}'`
if [ "$EndDate" = "$DatePlus7"]
then
        echo "Certificate has expired or will do so within 7 days!"
        echo "(or is invalid/not found)"
else
        echo "Certificate is good for another week!"
fi
```

Ultimately I would like to be able to output `echo | openssl s_client -connect $host:$port 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -enddate -noout` as well for the admin, this appearing after the `fi` statement. Would anyone be able to help me sort this out?

Comment: It's usually a mistake to prematurely redirect std-err output to /dev/null. Do you know where in the pipeline it is failing? Did you try executing just `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port` and if that is clean, then add the next segment, until you see a problem. Good luck.

Comment: If you hit `ctrl-d` when the script is "hanging" does it recover and keep going? You probably just need to force `s_client` to terminate the connection instead of waiting for input.

Comment: So I let the script run for a decent amount of time, roughly 10-12mins and it would complete if I left it alone using my vanilla script. I'm also able to `ctrl-d` and it does recover. If I also just execute `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port` with the proper variables it runs fine no issues. @shellter Im not sure where in the pipeline it is failing either since I'm just beginning in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to start small and build up rather than to start big and debug down.

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem, which also just hangs:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
```

Now that the problem is so simple and narrow, googling "why would openssl s_client hang?" leads to [useful information](https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website) recommending `echo -n | ...` to "give a response to the server, so that the connection is released". That should be sufficient to get further (there are other problems).

Anyways, here's a shorter way to do this:

```
if openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2> /dev/null < /dev/null |
    openssl x509 -checkend $((60*60*24*7)) -noout -in /dev/stdin
then
  echo "The certificate is good."
else
  echo "The certificate expires within a week."
fi
```

Comment: So this is awesome and really brings things down a notch for me even though I'm still confused about the `2> /dev/null < /dev/null |` bit and why `-in /dev/stdin` is needed but ill research some more on those myself. This has been a great help so thanks, now I just have to add in the date and its golden!

Answer (score 0):

This will print the expiration date without hangup:

openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2> /dev/null < /dev/null | openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in /dev/stdin

Comment: Thanks I've already gotten that answer from @that_other_guy though!